# Firebase Action URL in development and production

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a custom action URL for password reset in my firebase project.

[image]

Here, I'm using the dev mode URL: `http://localhost:3000/auth/reset-password`

Now if I want to deploy the app, it looks as if I will have to change the URL back to my custom domain name like `www.mydomain.com/auth/reset-password.`

Will I have to do this every time, or is there any work around?

Comment: I would really like to know too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really did was that I used nextjs to check if I was in production or development, and based on that, I navigate my users. On the firebase dashboard, I didn't do anything.

I used the `ResetPassword` function and set the property of the actionUrl based on the above condition.